tkinter after function is not behaving as expected. What is the reason?
I am working on a GUI for a program that charges and discharges supercapacitors. In the CELL_DISCHARGE function, the program seems to process one iteration of countdown, but does not seem to call itself within the after function as expected. The program proceeds to the next step. This is the entire function:
def CELL_DISCHARGE():

    SCPI_instrument_frame.grid_forget()
    CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.grid()

    #cell discharge
    global Chroma_address
    global DAQ_address
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    myChroma = rm.open_resource(Chroma_address)
    my34970A = rm.open_resource(DAQ_address)
    ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Cell discharge for 3 minutes").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
    voltage_label = ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Voltage: ")
    voltage_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, orient="horizontal", length=180, mode="determinate")
    progress.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
    progress["maximum"] = 180

    print("cell discharge for 3 minutes") #3min is for test 10 min for live
    #debug
    #time.sleep(3)
    #myChroma = rm.open_resource(Chroma_address)
    #Chroma_status = myChroma.query("*IDN?") 
    #print("Chroma Serial:" + Chroma_status)
    #print("Line - 449") 
    #time.sleep(3)
    #my34970A = rm.open_resource(DAQ_address)
    DAQ_status = my34970A.query("*IDN?")
    print("DAQ Serial:" + DAQ_status)
    myChroma.write('CHAN 1') #discharge
    myChroma.write('MODE CCL')
    myChroma.write('CURR:STAT:L1 ' + str(Discharge_curr)) #CC, static, ch 1 (discharge), 1A
    myChroma.write('LOAD ON')
    
    my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@202,204,206,208,210,212,214,216,218)") #unaffected / set to discharge
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@302,304,306,308,310,312,314,316,318)") #unaffected / set to discharge
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@201,203,205,207,209,211,213,215,217,219)") #affected / set for in circuit
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319)") #affected / set for in circuit
    #debug*******************************************************************
    def countdown(count):
        if count > 0:
            progress["value"] = 180 - count
            CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()

            print(str(count) + ": Seconds Remaining - initial discharge")
            max_range = Num_samples + 101
            for t in range(101,max_range,1):
                code = 200 + (t)
                print(code)
                #serialcomm.write(str(code).encode())
                my34970A.write('MEAS:VOLTAGE:DC? AUTO, DEF, (@' + str(t) + ')')
                voltage = float(my34970A.read())
                print("Voltage for Channel " + str(t) + " = " + str(voltage) + " VDC")
                voltage_label.config(text="Voltage: " + str(voltage))
                CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()
                if msvcrt.kbhit():
                    ASCII_in = ord(msvcrt.getche())
                    if ASCII_in == 120:
                        break
            CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.after(1000, countdown, count -1)
        #time.sleep(1)
    countdown(180)

This was originally part of an issue where the GUI window was freezing because of the time.sleep function. The function has since been commented out and replaced with another function that calls itself every second instead of sleeping. I was expecting the program to count down from 180 and provide updates every second, but as mentioned before, it only processes one iteration and proceeds to the next step. I have created a separate script which runs perfectly as I expected in the main program:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def test_countdown(count):
    if count > 0:
        print(f"Count: {count}")
        progress['value'] = 180 - count
        label.config(text=f"Count: {count}")
        window.after(1000, test_countdown, count - 1)
    else:
        print("Countdown complete.")

window = tk.Tk()

# GUI setup
progress = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient="horizontal", length=180, mode="determinate")
progress.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
progress["maximum"] = 180

label = ttk.Label(window, text="Starting countdown...")
label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

# Start countdown
test_countdown(180)

window.mainloop()

I have also tried commenting out the msvcrt functions but there's no change.
Why are the two programs behaving so differently?

.after() does not block the flow, so it will return immediately and "proceeds to the next step" as you said in the question.  However, countdown() should iterate more than once.  How do you determine that it iterates only once?  It is better to provide a [mre].

@acw1668 I have determined that it only iterates once through the terminal. I can see the print statements in countdown() there, but the function ends and proceeds to the next step.

Is the CELL_DISCHARGE_frame or any widget containing it destroyed by the next step?  If it is any after function linked to it will be halted too.

@TlsChris Yes, I have CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.grid_forget() in the next function, but I’m confused on why the function doesn’t finish its recursive iterations before proceeding to the next step.

The after method puts an event into the event loop to run a function in n ms.  Then it continues.  The code after the CELL_DISCHARGE function runs micro seconds after countdown(180).  Experimenting .grid_forget doesn't cause the after loop to stop.  Only .delete seems to stop the loop.  What happens if you call the following function from an else: clause in the countdown function.  ie. it won't be called until the 180 loops have finished.

@TlsChris Same result. I add an else: clause to countdown to call the next function, yet the program processes only a single iteration of countdown() and proceeds on as it did before any changes were made.

Does it change anything if the CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.after(1000, countdown, count -1) is replaced with your tk top level object.  root, master, window, whatever you call it.  I'd do root.after(1000, countdown).  I assume you did remove the follow on function from the old flow of functions.

@TlsChris Same result as before but I think I'm close to understanding why. When I comment out all succeeding functions, countdown() does behave as expected with no freezing. In the whole program, when a current function finishes execution, it returns to a "master" function which contains all subsequent functions. For some reason, this is not compatible with the tkinter widgets, so I will call them individually at the end of each function instead of having them return to the "master" function. Consider this problem solved.
